# How To Unit Test React Component With react-intl, react-router-dom v4 and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm currently trying to unit test a function in a React Class Component. I've tried everything that I can come across to get access to the actual Component.

The application is currently setup as follows:

```
<IntlProvider ...>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>
</IntlProvider>
```

The Component I'd like to test, lets call it Users, is defined inside of  as:

```
<Route
    path="/users"
    render={(routeProps) => {
        return (
            <Users
                {...routeProps}
            />
        );
    }}
/>
```

The users component is as such:

```
type Props = {...}

type State = {...}

class Users extends Component<Props, State> {

    constructor(props: any) { super(props); }

    componentDidMount() { ... }

    componentWillUnmount() { ... }

    isReadOnly = (): boolean => {
        // determine if read only.
    }

}

export default withRouter(Users)
```

and I'm trying to test a function called `isReadOnly`. I need to perform setState() on the component before I can actually call the function however.

So far I've tried:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<OrderEntry {...props}/>);
```

But it throws an error: `ShallowWrapper::setState() can only be called on class components`

I figured this had to be because of the `BrowserRouter`. So I find that I need to wrap in `MemoryRouter` to get around this.

```
const wrapper = shallow(<MemoryRouter><Users {...props}/></MemoryRouter>);
const usersInstance = wrapper.find(Users).dive().instance();
usersInstance.setState(state);
```

This throws the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of null`

If I `console.log(wrapper)`, it outputs: `ShallowWrapper {}`.

I'm a bit lost on this one...I just need to be able to do 2 things - Set State, and Unit Test one of the Components Function.

Comment: What kind of state do you want to mock? If it comes from the URL i recommend you setup your memory router so that it is on that route. It is recommended to test your components how users see them, and not touch the inner workings. That will make your tests fragile. This is a great post why that is bad: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/testing-implementation-details

Comment: While Kent has his points, the logic that's involved with the function I'm testing has many scenarios that need to be tested for business use cases. I'm not checking if the  implementation of a particular component has a specific visible child element, etc. I want to see if a single function in a component returns True or False.

Comment: Is your Users component a class or a function component? and are you testing the default export of user (wrapped  component) or named export?

Comment: So I've just updated the question with better details of the structure of the Users component. It's a class component. I guess I don't understand the last question you have. I'm just looking to test the isReadOnly() function based on the props I'd pass into the component.

Comment: Redux developers [suggest](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/WritingTests.md#connected-components) to export the unconnected component (`Users` in your case) and use it in the tests. That way, you have complete control over the props passed to the rendered instance and, as a bonus, no issues with using enzyme's `setState`...

Comment: That did the trick @kidney! I don't know why that was so challenging to find online! I'd like to award the bounty to you if you would like it.

Comment: @smb I'm glad it helped. I posted the comment as answer, so feel free to accept it:) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux [docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests/#connected-components) suggest to export the unconnected component (`Users` in your  case) and use it in the tests. That way, you have complete control over the props passed to the rendered instance and, as a bonus, no issues with using enzyme's `setState`.

So something like:

```js
export class Users extends Component<Props, State> {

    componentDidMount() { ... }

    componentWillUnmount() { ... }

    isReadOnly = (): boolean => {
        // determine if read only.
    }
}
export default withRouter(Users);
```

And in tests:

```js
import {Users} from "./Users";
```